# Programmatically log on to a site

Tags: authentication, https

I am not sure if this fits better on StackOverflow, but here goes:

I want to programmatically log on to:
http://wrds-web.wharton.upenn.edu/wrds/index.cfm?true

I tried capturing the log on url using [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647), but to no avail.
Is this a server side script that I cannot capture? If so how can I do the log on?

Comment: What happens if you send the username and password as POST requests? It looks like that should work.

Comment: I am afraid I am new to this and must admit I am not familiar with the POST request. Reading about it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't see a "login URL" because the form uses the POST method. The method you will need to use depends on the language. In Python, you could [use urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) for example.

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to do this using C# I need to search SO?

Comment: There is already a related question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/524525/how-to-login-to-html-form-using-post-vars-in-c-net

Comment: Thanks. I'll read through and ask more on SO if I don{t get it.